# How do you say "good point"?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation, interjections

For example:

> A: I don't think that's a good idea, because if you do x, y will happen

> B: Good point! I agree!

How could this be expressed in Esperanto?

I have thought of these possible translations:

> Bona ideo! - I like this one, but it still doesn't seem applicable for all situations. Because "good point" is refering to a specific argument, not an entire idea.

> Bona montrigxo! - this seems very clumbsy, and possibly wrong. But the idea of it is "that thing that became shown is good".

> Bona (el)penso! - this is my favorite, because it seems like it would work anywhere and it seems very natural

Which of these is the best translation? Is there a better one? Is there a better way to express this same idea without a literal translation?

Comment: Citation: «Because "good point" is refering to a specific **argument**» I think the answer is here :-)

Answer (score 5):

"Point" estas [argumento](https://vortaro.net/#argumenti_kd) ĉi-okaze. Do

Bona argumento! Mi konsentas.

Answer (score 3):

Dum ĉiutaga parolado mi dirus `fakte!`, `prave!` aŭ `vi pravas!`.

Kiam oni uzas tiujn eblojn kiel ekkriajn vortetojn, oni iel ankaŭ montras samopiniecon (almenaŭ tujan, tio povas ŝanĝiĝi post momenta cerbumo).

Answer (score 3):

Trafe! (from 'trafa' - spot on).

Answer (score 2):

"Prave", "vi pravas", or "ĝuste" is what I've seen the most and any of those feel way more natural and faster than "bona elpenso" or similar calques. It's better not to copy+paste every English word when speaking or translating.